# UITextField becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to move my first responder on using tags in a tableview cell. I've set _txtFieldActive to pick up the active UITextFields tag. I can see this when I press the next button on the keyboard via NSLog. Now however I can't seem to figure out how to resignfirstresponder on that tag, and then move my first responder onto tag 102?? I get an error on the line of code trying to assign tag 102 to *tmp.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  switch (textField.tag)
  {
    case 101:
      //Do Nothing do not want to close keyboard but move on to next UITextField

      if (_txtFieldActive.tag == 101)
      {NSLog(@"Tag = 101");
      UITextField *tmp = [textField.tag == 102];
      [tmp becomeFirstResponder];
  }
break;

case 102:
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

return YES;

}
```

Many thanks all for your help in advance for any pointers.

Jon.

Comment: And Xcode is fine with `[textField.tag == 102];`? EDIT: Oh, no... it's not. I just read that part of your question.

Comment: That is the bit I'm lost with nhgrif. My mind has gone. Can't sort that line of code out??

Comment: I'm trying to tell it to move to text field tagged 102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a reference to a view in the current view's hierarchy with a given tag, we need to call `viewWithTag:`.

```
if (_txtFieldActive.tag == 101) {
    NSLog(@"Tag = 101");
    UITextField *tmp = [self.view viewWithTag:102];
    [tmp becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Try that on for size.

If this is a `UITableViewController` subclass rather than a `UIViewController` subclass, you *might* need `[self.tableView viewWithTag:102];`, but `self.view` **should** work in either case.

Comment: I had incompatible controller types as I assigned tmp to UITextField. Changed to UIView and all now works. Many thanks for your quick response. I can now sleep easy tonight.